# Проверка на отсутствие строки в файле

Tags: c#, циклы

Есть программа, которая генерирует код по двум выбранным параметрам (цвет и капитель). Сами параметры хранятся в текстовом файле, в виде строк формата **цвет:капитель:ссылка**.

Пример:

```
102:classic:capitels/0206102.png
103:nonstandard1:capitels/0301103.png
104:seriya:capitels/0405104.png
```

Некоторые капители отсутствуют в определенных цветах. В этом случае, необходимо, чтобы программа выводила определенную строку.

Программа:

```
List<string> data = new List<string>();
string[] chosen_colors;
string[] chosen_caps;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var splitChars = new[] { ':' };

    try
    {
        data = File.ReadLines("config.txt").ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Файл конфигурации не найден:\n" + e.Message);
    }
}

private void generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chosen_colors = colorsList.CheckedItems.OfType<string>().ToArray();
    chosen_caps = capList.CheckedItems.OfType<string>().ToArray();

    foreach (string cap in chosen_caps)
    {
        code.Text += "'" + cap + "': {\n"; 
        foreach (string s in data)
        {
            string[] array = s.Split(new char[] { ':' }, 3);
            if (array[1] == cap)
            {
                foreach (string chosenColor in chosen_colors)
                {
                    if (array[0] == chosenColor)
                        code.Text += "\t'" + array[0] + "':'" + array[2] + "',\n";
                }
            }
        }
        code.Text += "},\n";
    }
}
```

Т.е. сейчас, если выбранной капители нету в цвете 102, то программа ничего не выведет. Мне же необходимо выводить строку вида **'102' : '/no-capitel.png'**, как написать проверку на отсутствие выбранной капители в определенном цвете?

Надеюсь объяснил понятно

Comment: Перебрать все строки с 102 в начале, проверить наличие в них нужной капители, если не нашлось - вывести. В чем проблема?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как конкретно это можно реализовать в теле цикла

Comment: Вот ровно так и можно реализовать. С чем <b>конкретно</b> проблемы?

Comment: Завести переменную с результатами перед циклом. Пройтись в цикле и поискать нужные данные, занеся найденное в переменную. Проверить после цикла переменную с результатами, нашлось ли что-нибудь и выполнить нужные действия. Готово. А по хорошему надо бы реализовать отдельный класс который будет искать и возвращать результат.

Comment: @AlexKrass А класс-то зачем?! bool HasCapitel (fileName, color, capitelName) и никаких классов.

Comment: Не рекомендую использовать двоеточие как разделитель, так как оно может входить в имя диска c:\ хотя и запрещено в именях файлов. Лучше использовать вертикальную черту `|`

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, затем, что помещать логику обращения к текстовым данным(считайте модель) в пользовательском интерфейсе не есть хорошо.

Comment: @AlexKrass Всякая функция помещается в пользовательский интерфейс? Упаси меня от такого языка...

Comment: Господа, ответье на вопрос пожалуйста

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: можно `**так**` сделать полужирный ))

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте как-то так:

```
var data = File.ReadLines(path)
               .Select(s => s.Split(new[] { ':' }, 3))
               .Select(triple =>
                           new
                           {
                               ColorIdx = int.Parse(triple[0]),
                               Capital = triple[1],
                               Reference = triple[2]
                           });
var colors = new HashSet<int>(data.Select(o => o.ColorIdx));
var dict = data.GroupBy(o => o.Capital)
               .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                             g => g.ToDictionary(o => o.ColorIdx, o => o.Reference));

foreach (var entry in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Capital: " + entry.Key);
    var colorMapping = entry.Value;
    foreach (var color in colors)
    {
        string reference;
        if (colorMapping.TryGetValue(color, out reference))
            Console.WriteLine("\tColor: {0}, reference: {1}", color, reference);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("\tColor: {0}, reference: default", color);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string result="";

//Формируем лист цветов, которые еще не встречались в обработке (изначально он повторяет список выбранных цветов)
    List<string>ColorsStillNotUsed=chosen_colors.Tolist(); 

      foreach (string record in data) //Перебираем записи из файла
       {
        //не используй разделитель ":", потому что в записях используется путь, могущий содержать такой символ.
       string[] parts = record.Split(new char[] { '|' }); 
       if(parts.Length==3) //Синтаксис строки в файле правильный 
        {
        if(chosen_colors.Contains(parts[0])&&chosen_caps.Contains(parts[1]))//Если цвет и капитель соответствуют выбранным
         { 
           ColorsStillNotUsed.RemoveAll(x=>x==parts[0]); //Убираем цвет из списка неиспользованных
           result+=string.Format("\t'{0}:{1}',\n", parts[0],parts[2]);//Добавляем в запись
          }
         }
        }   
      foreach (string unused in ColorsStillNotUsed) //Перебирая цвета, выбранные но не встреченные, генерируем соответствующие строки
       {
         result+=string.Format("\t'{0}:{1}',\n", unused,"/no-capitel.png");
       }
```

Неиспользованные цвета будут всегда в конце списка. Если порядок важен, можно помещать результат не в строку а в массив или IEnumerable и потом отсортировать строки Alphanumericом по первым символам (номер цвета).

Comment: Ошибка в `if (chosen_colors.Contains(parts[0]) && chosen_caps.Contains(parts[1]))` Значение не может быть неопределенным.
Имя параметра: source

Comment: Писал прямо тут, без проверки синтаксиса. Попробуйте заменить if(parts==3) на if(parts.Length==3) возможно в этом причина. Вообще любой код на этом ресурсе призван всего лишь показать направление в котором нужно двигаться, как правило отсутствуют даже элементарные проверки на возможные ошибки, ведь подразумевается, что задающий вопрос его самостоятельно творчески переработает под свои конкретные нужды.